# How to return the focus to a textInput in a browser

Tags: facebook, apache-flex, focus, textinput

I need to focus a text input into the Facebook login popup. I am using a virtual keyboard to simulate a physical one, but when I click a key, the text input lose focus and the letter is not written into the field.

How could I maintain the focus in the text input?

Comment: Have you tried txtInput.setFocus()

Comment: Another thought: use `callLater` to call `txtInput.setFocus()` after a delay

Comment: the problem is that i cant refer to the text input into the browser... i dont know how i could get the text input (the mail text input) into the facebook log in which is a browser window

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the problem is that i cant refer to the text input into the browser... i dont know how i could get the text input (the mail text input) into the facebook log in which is a browser window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to another solution... Using `getElementsByTagName('theElementID')`, I could get a reference to the textInputs in the browser, and I could modify its attributes...

For example,

```
emailStringObject =this.html.htmlLoader.window.document.getElementById('email');
emailStringObject.value="example@correo.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if creating your own virtual keyboard is a smart idea since all mobiles already have one in there, you just need to set `useSoftKeyboard` in Flex.

Also, you can always remove focusability to your components by setting focusEnabled and hasFocusableChildren to false.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help, but the proble is that i am not developing for mobile devices, i am interested in developing for all in one PCs... Another idea??? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes i tried seting focusEnabled false for every key of the virtaul keyboard, and for the Vbox which contains it, but unfortunatelly, it didnt work... I dont know if there is a way to mantain the focus in the input of the browser... Thakns J_A_X

Comment: Wait, the text input is in HTML and not Flex?

Comment: Yes, i mean, i open the facebook login browser into a new window, i add my virtual qwerty and when i press a key, i lose the focus and the key is pressed but not tiped into the inputText in the facebook page...

Comment: I really don't understand why you're using a Flex app, in a browser, just for a virtual keyboard and expect it to work within a focusable text input.  Second, why don't you just make an Air browser to do this instead that has a virtual keyboard?  I guess the other solution would be to either create a weird javascript hack or just use html/javascript to create the virtual keyboard...  either way, what you're doing right now is grossly inefficient.